# How do I forward from an IP address on my *local* network to a remote machine via SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I feel like this should be much easier than it's turning out to be - but basically:

- On my local home network, I have an IP camera at IP address `192.168.0.106:80` and `192.168.0.106:554` (camera configuration & RTSP stream ports, respectively).
- I have a VM running in Azure - I would like to securely forward traffic from that IP camera up to the VM.
  Based on this post, I would imagine something like this should work:

`ssh -L 192.168.0.106:80:localhost:80 -L 192.168.0.106:554:localhost:554 user@azure-vm-ip-address`

However, I've had no luck with this (and many variations on this). Either the port forwarding fails when the SSH connection is established, or localhost:80 is unresolvable on the remote VM.

Any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: I think you should do it backwards, with `-R` instead of `-L`: `ssh -R 80:192.168.0.106:80 -R 554:192.168.0.106:554 user@remote`. You want to be able to access the _local_ camera _from_ your remote server, right?

Comment: Correct, I want to access the *local* camera from the *remote* server. When I try it backwards that way, I get these errors:

`ssh -R 80:192.168.0.106:80 -R 554:192.168.0.106:554 user@remote`

"Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 80
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 554".

Comment: That may be because you don't have right to bind to ports < 1024 on the remote server. Usually, only root can do that. Use some higher ports, like 8080 or 8554: `ssh -R 8080:192.168.0.106:80 -R 8554:192.168.0.106:554`.

Comment: That did the trick!

Comment: @Mosvy make your 2 comments into an answer.